# Visual Studio Project Name with containing ".com"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, naming

I work with Visual Studio 2010. I wanted to create a Project (Windows Forms Application) with the Name:

MyCompany.MyApplication.CommunicationConfiguration.Test

If I want run this project I get the error message:

```
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program '...\bin\Debug\MyCompany.MyApplication.CommunicationConfiguration.Test.exe'. Access is denied.
```

After trying with different names and option I found out that visual studio has problem if the project name contains '.Com'.

So names like '.Com.Test' , 'HelloWorld.Communication' etc. throws exceptions. But if '.com' is the end of the name there is no problem.

My question now is, if someone knows if there is a rule which says that '.com' is not allowed in project names unless at the end of the name. I didn't found any rule in the internet and also visual studio doesn't warn by creating a project with '.com' inside the name.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards

rhe1980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting a repro for this at all, Windows 7 x64.  This is almost surely environmental, most likely related to your anti-malware software.  Looks like it might fumble the parsing of the filename, giving up the ghost when it contains multiple dots.  The .com part of the problem is somewhat significant, it is the filename extension for 16-bit non-relocatable programs back in the MS-DOS days.

Try this on another machine.  You could try killing processes with Taskmgr.exe one by one to find the trouble-maker.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: Thanks a lot for your answer! You are right. It's not a Visual Studio problem. I ran the application on a virtual machine and there it worked fine! I think I have to take a look to the system policies from our company. Thanks again for your help!